# What's the meaning of including 'random salt' in password hashing of django framework?

Tags: django, passwords, hash, salt

I'm a pretty newbie in Django framework. While just walking around the django's default authentication system, I found that django stores user's password in `algorithm$salt$hashed` format. And the salt is not same for every single user; django generates every new salt for each user.

I've made several web pages and got many chances using other open source softwares, but there was always only 'one' salt string for hashing.

So, my question is:

1. Why django uses 'random' salt beside 'one' salt string?
2. Why django stores it in same column with password hash?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why django uses 'random' salt beside 'one' salt string?

Because if you would have one salt you could generate rainbow tables for your database easier than when there are random salts.

If you would like to generate rainbow tables to decrypt django hashes you would have to generate tables for each different salt in database. Generating of rainbow tables take very long time, it's just brute force or dictionary attack.

> Why django stores it in same column with password hash?

I don't know what are you specifically asking about but there are probably 2 answers.

-It's stored because someone designed it that way. It could be on salt field and it wouldn't matter.

-When user send password via form django join salt to string and than calculate sha1 and check if it match the one in db.

Comment: Really appreciate your help. I asked no.2 because i didn't understand the reason of no.1. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The random salt prevents using a rainbow table to quickly decrypt all passwords in the table. Instead they have to do each one separately.

Answer (score 1):

The practice of salting a password is intended to make it more difficult for an attacker to brute-force crack the passwords you've stored. [More info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29).

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I knew the purpose of salt in hashing. My question is not just for salt.